# CSort сортировка

Tags: yii

Делаю регистронезависимую сортировку.

```
$sort = new CSort;
$sort->multiSort=true;
$sort->defaultOrder = 'is_active DESC, lower(filter_name) asc'; //сортировка фильтров по алфавиту, сначала активные потом неактивные

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BsListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($filters, array(
        'sort'=>$sort,
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize' => count($filters),
        )
    )),
```

Но все равно сначала выводится 'ВВВ', потом 'ббб'. Сам запрос в ide отрабатывает корректно. `select filter_name,id from tbl_filters where users_id = 16173 order by is_active DESC, lower(filter_name)` В чем пожет быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function getLowerCaseFilterName()
       {
            return mb_strtolower($this->filter_name);
       }

    $sort->defaultOrder = 'is_active DESC, lowerCaseFilterName';
```